# Facebook Stream.GetComments is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am using Facebook Toolkit (the old REST API LIB).
I have 2 users with comments in FB. 
both have the right permissions for my application.
When I launch Stream.Getcomments I get empty result in one user, and in the other one I get good result.

I tried using the FQL and it still returns empty. When using Facebook FQL test console they offer on their site - it is working ok.

What can it be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook Toolkit is pretty much dead and has a number of bugs. I would suggest switching to the newer Facebook C# SDK. You can find info about that here: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ and here: http://microsoft.com/facebook